# Noisy rendering problem, trying to get back to previous render results

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, denoise

I don't know what I've done wrong but my renderes are now coming very noisy and blotchy no matter how high I raise the sample count.

I had earlier renders that looked sharp and clean like the 1st image and suddenly something happened that everything comes out like the 2nd image.

[image: 100 Samples]

[image: 500 Samples]

Comment: Hello, maybe Z fighting? (overlapping faces)

Comment: Did you lower the light bounces? I had an issue like this once where I lowered them to decrease my render time, but instead got a result similar to yours

Comment: It looks like an object (earlier version?) hidden in the viewport, but set to render

Comment: Please add a minimal blend file using blend.exchange that showcases the issue and provide additional info on your setup and versions

Comment: So... I kept tweaking some render settings and also replaced my HDRI and asphalt material and one of those things did it... unfortunately not sure which one. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Phönix64, I'm not sure how to do that as the project file is 543 MB. Is there a function to simplify the project file?

Comment: Additionally, I've been able to remove the noisy effect most visible on the hood of the red car, BUT when animated it's nightmarish. I've attached a link to a comparison of the same animation with a few changes to some materials. https://imgur.com/a/7GO6Jpl